# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website which utilises the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div onclick="linkPopup()"></div>
<button type="button" id="hidePopup" onclick="hidePopup()">Cancel</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function linkPopup(questionNumber) {
        document.getElementById('linkPopup').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('addLink').setAttribute('onclick', 'addLink(' + questionNumber + ')');
    }

    function hidePopup() {
        document.getElementById('linkPopup').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

For some reason I get the following error in Chrome's developer tools:

> Uncaught TypeError: hidePopup is not a function

What is the route of this issue and how can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Where is that code sitting in the document?

Comment: Either way, spend some time to learn more about event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that `id='hidePopup'` was conflicting with `hidePopup()` as they have the same name.

The solution was to change the id to something other than 'hidePopup'.

Answer (score 0):

```
id="hidePopup" onclick="hidePopup()"
```

Your element id is conflicting with the function name.

To avoid this:

1. Avoid globals. (Wrap functions in Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE) or in functions you pass to an event handler like load or DOM Ready).
2. Bind your event handlers to elements using JavaScript (e.g. `addEventListener()` or jQuery's `on()`) instead of using intrinsic event attributes.

Comment: working with conflicting values http://jsfiddle.net/496n91au/3/ , i think this question is about wrong placing of script tag